# Using the Year in one cell to determine the contents for another cell

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is have a value put into a column based on the year in the other column. The year column is in MM/DD/YYYY format. I am not a very experienced VBA programmer, but I am trying to learn it as fast as I can.

I've already tried using the Year() function in an IF statement to see if it will show the text I want it to, but it shows nothing in the cell.

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D9")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If IsEmpty(cel) And Year(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = Year(2020) Then
        cel.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Test"
    End If
Next cel
```

Nothing shows up in the cel -2 cell and I am unsure what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Year(2020)` = `1905` not `2020`  you want: `If IsEmpty(cel) And Year(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = 2020 Then`

Comment: I tried "If IsEmpty(cel) And Year(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = 2020 Then" and I got a Run-Time Error '13' of Type Mismatch.

Comment: Are any of the values in `cel.Offset(0, -1)` errors or text?

Comment: the date is in cel.Offset(0, -1), format is MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

`Year(2020)` as mentioned returns 1905 this is because it works with the raw number/serial number not formatted in any way. A date written in a cell as a date will be recognized as a date and the value will change but it will look the same through formatting. For example today's date is 43650 without formatting and `Year(43650)` returns 2019

Just write `2020` like beneath if you want to compare each `Year(date)` to that number

```
Sub yearTest()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D9")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If IsEmpty(cel) And Year(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = 2020 Then
            cel.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Test"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Also you can try out the formula in your sheet like =Year(C1) in cell D1 and then change the formatting of the date in C1 to see the non-existent effects.